# Added Multiple Elements in Selector how to .load() only once?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, selector

A really stripped down version:

Scenario two selectors I am animating and then loading an external page using `.load()`
It seems the `load()` is triggerd twice for `element_A` and `element_B` ...
Is there a way to have it only trigger once?

```
$('.element_A, .element_B').click(function(){

   //...

   $(".element_C").load("someFile", etc);

   //...

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**patrick dw** built the foundation for the solution. An indicator of some kind needed to be added for the load to be triggered only once.

```
$temp_LoadCounter = 0; // added

$('.element_A, .element_B').click(function(){

   //...

   $temp_LoadCounter += 1; // added

   if ($temp_LoadCounter == 1) { // added

      $(".element_C").load("someFile", etc);

   //...

   } // added

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag to indicate if the `.load()` has already run.

```
var triggered = false; // our flag

$('.element_A, .element_B').click(function(){
        // if it hasn't run yet, run it and set "triggered" to "true"
    if( !triggered ) {
        $(".element_C").load("someFile", etc);
        triggered = true;
    }
});
```

You can set it back to `false` in the callback for the `load` if needed.

Or if the reason why it is firing twice is that one of the elements in the selector is nested inside the other, then it is because the event is bubbling.

You can prevent bubbling with `return false;` or the [`event.stopPropagation()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method.

```
$('.element_A, .element_B').click(function( event ){
        // prevent the event from bubbling and triggering the handler again
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(".element_C").load("someFile", etc);

});
```

Comment: hi patrick dw. 
You definitely pointed me into the right direction which was the key to the solution!!! 

Method one was the key in helping solve the problem. The only issue was that once the trigger was set back to true after ajax load it was available fast enough for it to be available for the second run. Even if it is put at the very end of the last line of the relevant code. I ended up using a counter which works beautifully.
I will add it as an answer to this thread.
 
Method 2 didn't have any effect even though the container the content is loaded into is nexted within element_B.